# Integrability of composite functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a Riemann-integrable function on a closed interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let g be a function on $\mathbb{R}$. What conditions must g satisfy so that $g \circ f$ is also Riemann-integrable ? Thank you!

Comment: @WilliamSun The answer to the linked question shows that if $g$ is Riemann-integrable then it is not necessary that $g \circ f$ is Riemann-integrable. The question here is different, so it is not a duplicate. I am voting to close it as off-topic, though, because of the lack of context.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Originally I planed to put the post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20045/about-the-riemann-integrability-of-composite-functions in my answer below as a duplicate of the question. But the link I gave in my comment mentioned the post below in the comment section, which I think will provide the op with other useful informations. Another problem is I attempted to change the link of duplicate but I haven’t figure out how to do it.

Comment: @WilliamSun I don't think it's possible to change the link of duplicate once you've voted. You've written a good answer, and I've upvoted it. But sadly this post will probably be closed as off-topic unless the OP improves it by providing more context.

Answer (score 2):

See this post [Riemann Integrability of Compositions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20045/about-the-riemann-integrability-of-composite-functions)

> If $f$ is a Riemann integrable function defined on $[a,b],\ g$ is a differentiable function with non-zero continuous derivative on $[c,d]$ and the range of $g$ is contained in $[a,b]$, then $f\circ g$ is Riemann integrable on $[c,d]$.

Quote from [Is the composite function integrable?](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Lu99.pdf) See the last result mentioned in the paper.